# Python Text Based Game Display

Tags: python, console, char, python-idle

I am trying to write a text based game in Python, but have reached a problem. I have my character move from one position to another in the Console, but every time the user presses a key, the character disappears. In order to see the character again, the user must press a key. Here is my code:

```
import os
import msvcrt

class Frog:
    X = 0
    Y = 0

    def __init__(self, x, y):
            self.X = x
            self.Y = y

    def Draw(self):
            for y in range(self.Y):
                    print ""
            print ' ' * self.X + '#'



    def Update(self):
            if msvcrt.kbhit() == True:
                    if msvcrt.getch() == 'a':
                            if self.X > 0:
                                    self.X = self.X - 1
                    if msvcrt.getch() == 'd':
                                    self.X = self.X + 1
                    if msvcrt.getch() == 'w':
                                    self.Y = self.Y - 1
                    if msvcrt.getch() == 's':
                                    self.Y = self.Y + 1






frog = Frog(0,0)


def Draw():
    frog.Draw()
    os.system('cls')

 def Loop():

    while 1:      

                    frog.Update()
                    Draw()



Loop()
```

Does anyone know what is causing this? All help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You clear the screen immediately after drawing, rather than before drawing. Thus, the thing you just drew is erased.

```
def Draw():
    frog.Draw()
    os.system('cls')
```

Try switching the order:

```
def Draw():
    os.system('cls')
    frog.Draw()
```